# Does Tensorflow support Keras models fit() method with eager execution?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am training a Keras model (`tf.keras.models.Sequential`) calling its method `fit()`.

Since I enabled eager execution, training time (for the same number of epochs) went up from 20.1s to 49.4s. Also, training didn't seem to converge anymore, as loss remained around 9 (without eager execution it went down to 1), while method `fit()` didn't even report the requested metric "accuracy" anymore.

Is eager execution support for Keras models? Note that I am calling method `fit()` on the model, not using an estimator.

Here the snippet of code that declares the model and does the training. Using TF 1.7 for GPU installed with pip3.

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(11,)) ,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu') ,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax')
])

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
# optimizer = 'adam'
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_y, epochs=200, batch_size=64, verbose=2)
```

UPDATE: filed issue #18642 on Tensorflow GITHUB.

Comment: Yes, `tf.keras` is meant to be compatible with eager execution. In fact the ["Getting Started with Eager Execution"](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager#create_a_model_using_keras) guide uses it.

If you're seeing a different in behavior between graph and eager execution, I'd suggest [filing a bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new).

Comment: Unfortunately the example you mention uses `tfe.GradientTape()` to fit the dataset, it doesn't try to call `tf.keras.models.Sequential.fit()`.

They provide another example for eager execution and Keras, which again doesn't call `fit()` but uses an estimator.

I can make `tfe.GradientTape()` work, but `fit()` doesn't seem to converge (the loss doesn't go down), and doesn't report the metrics it should.

I will improve the title of my question to clarify the issue is with calling the `fit()` method on a Keras model. I also plan to open an issue on GITHUB, will update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I reported on tensorflow got this answer:

> Thank you for the bug report. We have a fix for this issue, that will
>   show up on GitHub soon.

See issue  [#18642](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18642) on GITHUB for Tensorflow.

Based on this, I understand that method `fit()` of Keras models will be supported with eager execution, once the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from the Tensorflow site found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager)

> There are many parameters to optimize when calculating derivatives. TensorFlow code is easier to read when structured into reusable classes and objects instead of a single top-level function. Eager execution encourages the use of the Keras-style layer classes in the tf.keras.layers module. Additionally, the tf.train.Optimizer classes provide sophisticated techniques to calculate parameter updates.

That means keras layers and subsequent models are allowed using Eager execution.
As for your timing, the link also mentions how using eager stops building of graphs.

> TensorFlow's eager execution is an imperative programming environment that evaluates operations immediately, without an extra graph-building step. Operations return concrete values instead of constructing a computational graph to run later.

This may make it harder for your model to run given the number of DENSE layers you have. Someone may correct me on that because I have not done much work with DENSE layers before, or it has been a long time since I have. If that does not work then I would look into your loss function. [This answer may help if that becomes a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827207/9659107).

Everything else looks alright though. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Ok I see what you are saying Fate. Yeah the first link uses Sequential model, but Gradient tape fro gradient decent. Reading deeper into the eager tutorial shows that they only use Gradient tape as well. Here is what the tutorial says about training:

> Automatic differentiation is useful for implementing machine learning algorithms such as backpropagation for training neural networks. During eager execution, use tfe.GradientTape to trace operations for computing gradients later.tfe.GradientTape is an opt-in feature to provide maximal performance when not tracing. Since different operations can occur during each call, all forward-pass operations get recorded to a "tape". To compute the gradient, play the tape backwards and then discard. A particular tfe.GradientTape can only be computed once, subsequent calls throw a runtime error.

So maybe as of right now only Gradient tape and the estimator method are what you are supposed to use with eager.

Comment: Keras layers `tf.keras.layers` work with eager execution, but method `fit()` of `tf.keras.models.Sequential()` doesn't, as far as I can tell. In fact, both examples I found of Keras + eager execution on TF GITHUB don't call the `fit()` method: one uses the gradient tape and the other an estimator. See: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/core/get_started/eager.ipynb and also https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist_eager.py

Answer (score 1):

When reading the `compile` method on Model ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#methods_2)), you can find an argument, `run_eagerly`:

> `run_eagerly`:    Bool. Defaults to False. If True, this Model's logic will not be wrapped in a tf.function. Recommended to leave this as None unless your Model cannot be run inside a tf.function.

So by default, a tf.keras.Model will default to running through **graph execution**, not eager execution.